# Tkinter - Disable button on click made in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I need to change the background color and disable the button that is clicked in the following code. I have tried to pass button in the command for the button but it doesn't seem to work.

I tried adding to my lambda call on the button variable: btn=button and then passing that through my function call, but I get the error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'button' referenced before assignment"

How can i add to my disable_btn() function to disable the button and turn it grey.

Thanks

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font as tkfont

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        self.frames["StartPage"] = StartPage(parent=container, controller=self)

        self.frames["StartPage"].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.grid(columnspan=5, rowspan=5)

        self.populate = tk.Button(self, text='Populate Data', command=lambda : self.data())
        self.populate.pack(side='top')

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.frame, borderwidth=0)
        self.canvas.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)


    def data(self):
        row = 1
        for x in range(5):
            print(x)
            label = tk.Label(self.canvas, text='Line {}'.format(row))
            label.grid(row=row, column=1, padx=15, pady=15)

            text = tk.Text(self.canvas, width=5, height=1)
            text.grid(row=row, column=2, padx=15, pady=15)

            button = tk.Button(self.canvas, text='Click me', bg='white', command=lambda line=row:stored_functions.disable_btn(self, line))
            button.grid(row=row, column=3, padx=15, pady=15)

            row+=1


class stored_functions():
    def disable_btn(self, line):
        print('Disabled the button on line {}'.format(line))
        btn.configure(state='disabled', bg='grey')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: you don't need to pass `self` as argument to the button function or maybe you do, but wha is `btn` in `disable_btn`? it is not defined

Comment: Ok. I have removed that. I am not 100% clear on when i should/shouldnt be using self in classes. This is still pretty new to me. But I still need to somehow pass a reference to which specific button was pressed so I can disable it.

Comment: you usually never pass `self` to a method to reference the method's class, if you want to reference the button just use `button` and pass that to the function

Comment: Ok, so I did what you said, and removed the self, and just passed button. Now when I click the button on line one, i get the print statement "Disabled the button on line 1" but the button on line 5 (the last one made) is the one that changes colors and is disabled...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the button widget as an argument to the function associated with its command. However you can't do it in the same call as the one that creates the `Button` because it doesn't exist yet. A simple way to workaround that impediment is to do it in two steps:

```
    def data(self):
        row = 1
        for x in range(5):
            print(x)
            label = tk.Label(self.canvas, text='Line {}'.format(row))
            label.grid(row=row, column=1, padx=15, pady=15)

            text = tk.Text(self.canvas, width=5, height=1)
            text.grid(row=row, column=2, padx=15, pady=15)

            button = tk.Button(self.canvas, text='Click me', bg='white')
            button.grid(row=row, column=3, padx=15, pady=15)
            button.config(command=lambda btn=button, line=row: disable_btn(btn, line))

            row += 1


def disable_btn(btn, line):
    print('Disabled the button on line {}'.format(line))
    btn.configure(state='disabled', bg='grey')
```

Comment: Ah, ok this makes sense. I was basically doing this but trying to do it in 1 line and kept getting the error. Having to do it in 2 lines makes a lot of sense. Thank you!

Comment: Please note that `lambda line=row: disable_btn(button, line)` will always disable the last button. It should be `lambda button=button, line=row: disable_btn(button, line)`.